# Can OCaml PPXes return extensions to be parsed by other PPX extensions?

Tags: ocaml

Given a syntax extension that looks like this

```
let a = [%jsx div className="hello"]
```

I've got a PPX that converts it to (something like)

```
let a = ReactJS.create_element "div" ~props:(object%js val className = "hello" end)
```

I need OCaml to subsequently transform the %js syntax extension, which is provided by js_of_ocaml.

However, by the looks of things, the PPX extensions stuff does a single pass over the source, and doesn't recursively apply it.

Is it possible to make it do so? Or do I need to try to import the js_of_ocaml PPX and run it inside my own? Or is the best method to simply cut out the middleman and produce the same transformation in my own code?

Edit - More info:

So, it doesn't appear that the order of PPXes being applied is the issue here. I get the following:

`+ ocamlfind ocamlc -c -package reactjs,reactjs_ppx,react,js_of_ocaml,js_of_ocaml.ppx -o tutorial.cmo tutorial.ml
File "tutorial.ml", line 3, characters 14-99:
Uninterpreted extension 'js'.`

I have a feeling I'm producing the wrong AST though (again).
The code used to generate the `js%object` looks like this:

`Exp.extension ({txt="js"; loc=loc},
    PStr [
        Str.eval (
            Exp.object_ (
                Cstr.mk (Pat.any ()) fields
            )
        )
    ]
)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, as camlspotter said, but it's going to be a bit brittle (you need to rely on the order of ppx applications).

Please don't copy js_of_ocaml's ppx inside your application (or try to make the same transformation, it's a complicated one). It will break if we update the ppx.

I have been considering exposing some parts of the ppx as a library (in particular, the mapper) which you could then use. Could you get in touch on the js_of_ocaml bug tracker ?

Comment: So it turns out the stuff I needed was already exported - I just needed to pull it in to my project and now everything's happy!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a PPX chain having multiple `-ppx <ppx>` options to the compiler:

```
ocamlc -ppx a -ppx b input.ml
```

`input.ml` should be passed to PPX `a`, then its output should be sent to `b`, then finally the output is given to `ocamlc`.

With `ocamlfind`, you can specify multiple PPX packages like:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package ppx_A,ppx_B input.ml
```

to apply more than one PPX preprocessors.  The application order should be calculated depending on the package dependencies between `ppx_A` and `ppx_B`.  If `ppx_B` package depends on `ppx_A`, you do not need to mention `ppx_A`: `ocamlfind ocamlc -package ppx_B input.ml` automatically apply `ppx_A` before `ppx_B`.

Comment: So I took a peep at the ordering stuff, and it doesn't look like that's an issue: I've updated the question to reflect this